# Why can't I use the split() method in Python to split a string into a list from within a function?

Tags: python, list, function

I am unable to split a string into a list using a function in Python. However, when I do it without a function, it works. Here's my code:

```
def listAdder(list1):
    """ Function to split a string into a list. """
    text_line = "This is a string"
    list1 = text_line.split(' ')
    print(list1)    # printing the list to verify its status within the function.

list1 = []
listAdder(list1)
print(len(list1))    # printing the length of the list to verify its status outside the 
                     # function
```

The output:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'string']
0
```

The list is successfully created with the string elements split inside it within the function, as is evident from the output. However, the list remains empty when I try to verify its state out of the function.

What do I need to do to make the list retain its value outside the function?

EDIT: Got the solution:

```
def listAdder(list1=[]):
    text_line = "This is a string"
    list1 = text_line.split(' ')
    print(list1)
    return list1

list1 = listAdder()
print(len(list1))
```

This works as expected! Thanks

Comment: Have your tried to add `return list1` to your function and retrieve the returned list with `list1 = listAdder(list1)` or add `global list1` to your function?

Comment: Add a `global text_line` to the beginning of the function.

Comment: Try adding a return statement `return list1` and while calling the function store that return  value of function in a new list. It works!

Comment: @marcelh This worked: 

`def listAdder(list1=[]):
 text_line = "This is a string"
 list1 = text_line.split(' ')
 print(list1)
 return list1

list1 = listAdder()
print(len(list1))`

Comment: Your "solution" that uses a mutable default argument is a new, different bug waiting to bite you, not a solution to your problem. Either append to your list or return the new local list you created.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the updated list (by your function) to the variable in your main program, like below. Inside the listAdder function, when you assign the result of the split function, the initial list reference is lost, and hence not visible to your program main body.

```
def listAdder(list1):
    text_line = "This is a string"
    list1 = text_line.split(' ')
    print(list1)    # printing the list to verify its status within the function.
    return list1

list1 = listAdder(list1)
print(len(list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the scope of variables. Updating `list1` in the function does not update that object outside the scope of the function.

You can use a function without parameters and mark it with `global list1`, which allows it to alter `list1` that you have declared in the global scope.

```
def listAdder():
    global list1 # This allows it to modify the variable
    """ Function to split a string into a list. """
    text_line = "This is a string"
    list1 = text_line.split(' ')

list1 = []
listAdder() # No parameter
print(len(list1)) # Prints 4
```

This is considered poor practice, however, as it can be harder to reason about our code.

It is better to use a function to return a value.

```
def listAdder():
    text_line = "This is a string"
    return text_line.split(' ')

list1 = []
list1 = listAdder()
```

Comment: Thanks. That's an apt explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`list1` inside `listAdder` is local variable and it has nothing to do with `list1` which you create outside `listAdder`

To work with the same variable you should use `global` and then you don't need to define arguments

```
def listAdder():
    global list1  # inform function to use global variable when you use `=`

    text_line = "This is a string"
    list1 = text_line.split(' ')
    print(list1)

list1 = []   # it is global variable
listAdder()
print(len(list1))
```

But better is to use `return` to send result back to main code. It also doesn't need `list1` as argument. Inside function I use differn name to show that it is different variable

```
def listAdder():
    text_line = "This is a string"
    text_list = text_line.split(' ')
    print(text_list)
    return text_list

list1 = listAdder()
print(len(list1))
```

---

If you want to send some list to function and get result in this list then you should use `append()` or `extend()` (or `+=`) instead of `=`

```
def listAdder(text_list):
    text_line = "This is a string"
    
    #text_list.extend( text_line.split(' ') )
    text_list += text_line.split(' ')
    
    print(text_list)

list1 = []
listAdder(list1)
print(len(list1))
```